# Editing a Wordpress Multisite Main Site URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory, multisite

#### Some Context

I have a WordPress Multisite setup with **Sub-Directories** that looks like this :

- *`dev.agency.xyz`* - (Main site URL)
- *`dev.agency.xyz/pt/`* - (Portuguese version of the site)
- *`dev.agency.xyz/en/`* - (English version of the site)

Both PT and EN are subdirectory site URL that will always start like this before adding the subpages URL.

#### Goal

The language of the main site URL is *French* and I would like to make sure the URL for the main site is constantly `dev.agency.xyz/fr/` like the PT and EN sites.
Let me give you an example of the current situation versus the expected results :

#### Current Situation

Here are some URLs from the main website :

- *`dev.agency.xyz`* - Homepage URL
- *`dev.agency.xyz/agency/`* - Agency Page URL
- *`dev.agency.xyz/wp-admin/`* - WordPress Admin Dashboard URL

Note that for example that the EN site URLs looks like this :

- *`dev.agency.xyz/en/`* - Homepage URL
- *`dev.agency.xyz/en/agency/`* - Agency Page URL
- *`dev.agency.xyz/en/wp-admin/`* - WordPress Admin Dashboard URL

#### Expected result

I'd like to **force** the main site URL to behave like this :

- *`dev.agency.xyz/fr/`* - Homepage URL
- *`dev.agency.xyz/fr/agency/`* - Agency Page URL
- *`dev.agency.xyz/fr/wp-admin/`* - WordPress Admin Dashboard URL

#### The Problem

It seems that WordPress won't allow URL editing for the main site whereas for any subdirectory site added to the network, WordPress will allow URL editing.

#### What I've tried

I tried editing and adding a lot of things in `wp-config.php` but ended up leaving it as below because none of my modification were working as intended :

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

// Enable multisite
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

// Define the network as a subdirectory
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );

define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dev.agency.xyz' );
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

/* Ensure that connections work properly. */
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

Most of what I tried half or didn't worked when editing the `.htaccess` file, the only thing that seems to work is the code given in the [WordPress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/multisite/administration/#htaccess-and-mod-rewrite) which makes sure that `dev.agency.xyz/fr/wp-admin` leads to the admin dashboard of the main site, but still without remembering it :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

I think I'm trying to do something quite experimental, and I admit that it also confuses me when I'm confronted with the problem and looking for solutions. But hopefully I phrased this as clear as I could so you guys can lead me to the most adequate solution.

I'm not used to work on `.htaccess` files, so I might have missed something. But I am sure there is a way to make the links work fully as intended.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good fit for Stack Overflow.  This might or might not qualify as "programming."  There is a much better place that you could ask instead: [wordpress.se].

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'll try posting my problem and look for solution over there too, thank you for the advice. If I find a fix anywhere, I will add an answer here so people know its fixed.

Comment: If you have posted there, you should delete it here.  Cross-posting within the Stack Exchange network is not permitted.